# Tabulator ajaxResponse with complex nested json data properties

Tags: algorithm, debugging, tabulator

can someone help with passing the below json data to Tabulator thru the ajaxResponse function? Would be much helpful for a complete example of how to construct a table from the json data below. Thanks advance for your help.

Below is the Data Loading Error from Chrome Console: [Also attached screen capture of Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNAsf.png)

tabulator.min.js:3 Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type 
Expecting: array 
Received:  object 
Data:

> {5ofq7: {…}, l4uey: {…}, 66ute: {…}, f3wc2: {…}, v6lm2: {…}, …}
>
> > 5ofq7:
> >     id: "39570"
> >     item_key: "5ofq7"
> >     name: "AustralianSuper Pty Ltd"
> >     ip: "101.112.84.10"
> >
> > > meta:
> > >       9665u: "AustralianSuper Pty Ltd"
> > >       jrv58: "AustralianSuper High Growth"
> > >       syqxv: "ISF0031AU"
> > >       mbwaa: "100000"
> > >       clc6v: ""
> > >       og0n12: "4.47"
> > >       m0tyf: ""
> > >       mf8ge: "17.52"
> > >       r58wq2: "12.17"
> > >       af3q82: "10.37"
> > >       ri3w1: "9.86"
> > >       krmsm: ""
> > >       f8zyy2: "5.92"
> > >       kztr1: ""
> > >       pi5q4: "7.35"
> > >       luul4: "6.31"
> > >       p9vvi: ""
> > >       fi17d: ""
> > >       eft3z: ""
> > >       b7omg: ""
> > >       9n8sj: ""
> > >       187j5: ""
> > >       166p3: "8.71"
> > >       9k83f: "12.43"
> > >       v5jn5: "14.07"
> > >       8qs59: "AustralianSuper Pty Ltd"
> > >       8j6t8: "10496"
> > >       kvwkh2: "0.51"
> > >       g7pnc2: ""
> > >       dfka2: ""
> > >       zrpgi2: ""
> > >       lkg952: ""
> > >       o77jo: ""
> > >       15cc6: "Multisector Aggressive"
> > >       73vew: "Superannuation Fund"
> > >       n5i51: "Morningstar Aus Msec Aggressive TR AUD"
> > >       jvkfe: "Open"
> > >       t1yvr: "0"
> > >       kcn4h: "0"
> > >       hwdr8: "29.989"
> > >       ivfki: "49.708"
> > >       rzr0z: "2.119"
> > >       9bw4z: "2.911"
> > >       8cpa5: "4.042"
> > >       6hq0z: "6.91"
> > >       1y2l7: "1.69"
> > >       yl46p: "1.69"
> > >       ih8bm: ""
> > >       zds53: ""
> > >       v1y5k: ""
> > >       fq04j: ""
> > >       en2oj: ""
> > >       stvhv: ""
> > >       rjap92: "Admin"
> > >       rjap92-value: "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to hack together a solution that works, definitely can be improved on by more experienced developers. Thanks to #Arnauld and #Felix Kling - this solution is based on their SO contributions.

```
    <div id="example-table"></div>
    <script>
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        autoColumns:true,
        height: 500,
        layout: "fitData",
        layoutColumnsOnNewData:true,
        ajaxURL:"https://xxxxx.com/wp-json/frm/v2/forms/22/entries?",
        ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
           var obj = response;
           var res = [];
           Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {    //Convert nested objects to array of objects
               Object.keys(obj[k]).forEach(v => {
               (res[v] = (res[v] || { id: v }))[k] = obj[k][v];
                });
           });
         res=res.meta;                          //Select the required object from array
         var obj = res;
         var data =[];      //Convert object to required array format needed for Tabulator
             function toArray(obj) {     
             const result = [];
             for (const prop in obj) {
                 const value = obj[prop];
             if (typeof value === 'object') {
                result.push(value);
              }
              else {
              }
              }
        return result;
        }
    data=toArray(res);
    return data;
    },
    });
    </script>
```